# Symfony3 Force https to all generate error infinite loop

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, https

I have website build in Symfony3. I want to force for all routes https.

I add this to my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Main page working ok, user is redirect to version with https but on any subpage where in link is char "/" I have problem "Error: infinite loop"

For example this work fine:

https://www.example.com

https://www.example.com/subpage1

But this generate Error Infinite Loop:
https://www.example.com/subpage1/subpage2

When I remove force https in .htaccess everything work fine...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid to use `.htaccess` to do such things.
Unless you plan to only have some part of your site in https, do it with the vhost configuration file instead.

Here is a full example for Symfony 3 with Apache 2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com

    Redirect / https://www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.example.com/web
    <Directory /var/www/www.example.com/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/www.example.com/web/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

    ErrorLog /var/www/www.example.com/var/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/www.example.com/var/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Source: https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL